# Updating and emailing only checked records in tabular rows in Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

In a tabular form in Oracle Apex, how would you make it only update the checked off rows, and where would you put this process?

Do you add it to the existing ApplyMRU process as a condition?

I'm just currently stuck where I have a tabular form and I only want it to update the checked off rows and then send an email out to let people know that the status for that record has changed.

I've tried doing it based on time and date from a suggestion, but it's sending out every record verse just the ones I need.

Here's the current email code that's not working right, I don't want to pull it from the table directly, I'd rather it use the fields on the tabular forms and only email out the rows that have been checked off.

```
DECLARE  
   l_id           NUMBER;
   l_index        NUMBER;
   l_vc_arr2      apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
   lc_message     VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_pkey         NUMBER;
   l_date_wrote   DATE;
   l_sales        VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_client       VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_job          VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_who          VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_date_covered DATE;
BEGIN  
   FOR c1  
      -- Retrieve reqs primary key that have been covered  
      -- in the last 2 seconds by the salesman  
   IN (SELECT pkey  
       FROM reqs 
       WHERE  TO_CHAR ( (SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') < (TO_CHAR ( (date_covered + 1 / 10800), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'))     
       AND  sales = :p14_sales  
       AND covered IS NOT NULL)  
   -- Send an email for each req that has been covered  
   LOOP  
      SELECT date_wrote,  
             sales,  
             client,  
             job,  
             Who, 
             date_covered  
        INTO l_date_wrote,  
             l_sales,  
             l_client,  
             l_job,  
             l_who,  
             l_date_covered 
        FROM reqs  
       WHERE pkey = c1.pkey;  
      lc_message := 'Date Written   :' || l_date_wrote || CHR (10);  
      lc_message := lc_message || 'Sales          :' || l_sales || CHR (10);  
      lc_message := lc_message || 'Client         :' || l_client || CHR (10);  
      lc_message := lc_message || 'Position       :' || l_job || CHR (10);  
      lc_message := lc_message || 'Who Covered       :' || l_who || CHR (10);  
      lc_message := lc_message || 'Date Covered           :' || l_date_covered || CHR (10);  
      l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(  
            p_to     => 'some.name@somedomain.com',  
            p_from   => 'DO_NOT_REPLY@REQS',  
            p_subj   =>    ''  
                        || l_who  
                        || ' Has Covered '  
                        || l_job  
                        || ' at '  
                        || l_client  
                        || CHR (10),  
            p_body   => lc_message);  
      COMMIT;  
      apex_mail.push_queue ();  
   END LOOP;  
END;
```

I've been banging my head against a wall on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the correct arrays with PLSQL. Items in tabular forms map to a couple of arrays in session state.
[Apex documentation: Referencing Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_app.htm#CHDICJDA)
Checkboxes are special cases in this, as they will not create an entry in these arrays when they are not checked.
[Apex documentation: Referencing Arrays in an on-submit process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_app.htm#CHDGJBAB)

For example, I have a tabular form on EMP and there is a "[row selector]" column present. 
[image: Columns in report]

On webpage:
[image: selection of checkboxes on page]

Then I have this on-submit process:

```
-- loop over array f01
-- this will be the array holding the values for a checkbox column (in this case, the row selector pseudo column)
FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count 
LOOP
  -- show what is in array f01
  -- this will be the index position of the checked row in case of the row selector
  apex_debug.message('Value of array f01 at position'||i||': '||apex_application.g_f01(i));
  -- array f02 will be the next editable (or session state saving) column, in my case a display-but-session-state-saving column with the EMPNO
  apex_debug.message('Value of array f02 at position'||apex_application.g_f01(i)||': '||apex_application.g_f02(apex_application.g_f01(i)));
END LOOP;
```

The output in the debug:

```
Value of array f01 at position1: 2
Value of array f02 at position2: 7698
Value of array f01 at position2: 4
Value of array f02 at position4: 7566
```

So things to take note of:

- as in any tabular form, be aware of how the columns map to an array.
- position matters in this case, so switching columns around will alter
  the array they will map to
- checkbox columns do NOT create a row in their respective array when they are UNCHECKED
- this matters when looping over arrays and a checkbox column has to be checked

These are techniques very commonly used when working with manual tabular forms, which use [the APEX_ITEM api](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#CHDDCHAF).

So to make your email system work: loop over the checkbox columns, retrieve a PK from another array, and send a mail much like you do in your current loop.

---

Eg:

I took your code sample and adapted it. Note that I changed a few things:

- removed variables for each field and instead used a rowtype variable for ease of use
- removed the commit
- push the queue after the loop

---

```
DECLARE  
   l_checked_row  NUMBER;
   l_id           NUMBER;
   lc_message     VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_pkey         NUMBER;
   l_r_reqs       reqs%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN  
  FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count 
  LOOP  
    l_checked_row := apex_application.g_f01(i);
    -- assuming that array F02 maps to column PKEY from table REQS
    l_pkey        := apex_application.g_f02(l_checked_row);

    -- get details required for creating the mail body
    -- It's generally easier to just fetch the row instead of having to 
    -- define variables to cover every field you need.
    SELECT *  
      INTO l_r_reqs
      FROM reqs  
     WHERE pkey = l_pkey;  
    -- Dont forget that select into may generate no_data_found or too_many_rows !

    lc_message :=               'Date Written   :'         || l_r_reqs.date_wrote   || CHR (10);  
    lc_message := lc_message || 'Sales          :'         || l_r_reqs.sales        || CHR (10);  
    lc_message := lc_message || 'Client         :'         || l_r_reqs.client       || CHR (10);  
    lc_message := lc_message || 'Position       :'         || l_r_reqs.job          || CHR (10);  
    lc_message := lc_message || 'Who Covered       :'      || l_r_reqs.who          || CHR (10);  
    lc_message := lc_message || 'Date Covered           :' || l_r_reqs.date_covered || CHR (10);  
    l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(  
          p_to     => 'TESTER@TEST.com',  
          p_from   => 'DO_NOT_REPLY@REQS',  
          p_subj   =>    ''  
                      || l_r_reqs.who  
                      || ' Has Covered '  
                      || l_r_reqs.job  
                      || ' at '  
                      || l_r_reqs.client  
                      || CHR (10),  
          p_body   => lc_message);        
    -- avoid commits unless ab-so-lu-te-ly necessary. Apex implicit commits can make the flow hard enough to
    -- understand as it is.
  END LOOP;

  apex_mail.push_queue ();
END;
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I'm trying to figure out how to do just that, I'm not a developer but learning.

I'm trying to figure out how that would be structured in the email loop.

Comment: There is probably no real easy way of explaining all this. I advise just taking a look at the linked documentation, and try to understand how items in tabular forms get substituted to the session state. Once you get a grasp of that, this should be a lot clearer. Easiest way, imo: create a new page with a tabular form on it based on the emp table. Then just create a process with some debug lines in it to understand what is going on (run page in debug, then view debug).

Comment: As for how to use this: in my example code, array f02 would contain EMPNO, which is the PK for the EMP table. Thus, looping over this array will be much the same like you are looping over your cursor: loop over the array, and in the loop select the necessary data and then send a mail.

Comment: Tom, I did read the attached link, and I do understand how to make calls to the arrays, it's how to properly structure it into the email process I have, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: I added a code sample. Note I changed/simplified some things!

Comment: Tom, I can't thank you enough, that worked!

How to structure the process does make sense now, and I appreciate it that.

The only thing I did notice is that if 1 thing is checked off it sends out 1 email, if 3 things are checked off it sends out those 3 emails 3 times.

But this is a huge leap forward all the same and I can't thank you enough.